# On form submit, does the server ‘directly’ receive req or listen to changes in a particular place?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, forms, server-side

please forgive me if my question sounds naive. I researched on google, and several forums, but couldn’t find anything that is clear.

Here is my dilemma,

Step 1 -> Node.js Server is listening

Step 2 -> User on page ‘/new-users’. (POST, ‘/signup-controller)

Step 3 (& maybe Step 4) ->  Id like to know what happens here, before the server decides where to  take the data.

On step 1, Was the server listening to the local storage to see if any new requests are there?

Or, does it ‘directly’ receive the request in step 3?

I’ve always been under the impression that servers just listen to changes. Meaning it does not literally ‘receive’ req or res data.

Thanks a lot for reading my question and I look forward to any feedback.

EDIT: to clarify, does the client walk up to the server directly and hand over the data’s, hand to hand, or does the client store the data at some ‘locker’ or ‘location, and the server notices a filled locker, hence triggering the subsequent events?

Comment: The question is not clear, could you rephrase what you're asking?

Comment: it does not listen to changes. it listens to requests. When the user requests for any page or sends any data, the request is sent to the server with the appropriate data. the server responds accordingly and processes data based on the request.

Comment: Thanks Anitket. @Robert, because I don’t understand severs on a deep level, allow me to speak abstractly. Right after the submission, does the data from the form get temporarily stored somewhere, where the server noticed that there is a new request. Or does the client directly walk up to the server with the data and hands it over.

Answer (score 0):

No it will directly receive the request data and if you are using framework like express in node then you can use middleware to validate or check request data and move forward

Comment: Thanks for sharing the knowledge!

Answer (score 0):

The server only listen for a request, not for response
when it finds a request (req), operates with this request and bases od that must deliver a response (res) with data, files, error.. whatever..

Answer (score 0):

The server receives a POST og GET (Depending on the METHOD attribute in the FORM tag) - If you want to implement some logic to decide where to put the data, it should be done by the server, analyzing the data. Hidden input tags (Type="hidden") could assist supplying info. Like a hidden input tag saying "NEW" or "EDIT" and the "ID" to example.

Using an AJAX method instead lets you negotiate with the server before the final POST.

hth.
Ole K Hornnes

Comment: Thanks man, I appreciate the answer. So by that it means the client walks up directly to the server and hands him the form data? 

And yah I’m only talking about standard Post / Get requests. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**On step 1, Was the server listening to the local storage to see if any new requests are there?**
no, the server not listening the local storage, it listening the server port. and waiting the request.

**does it ‘directly’ receive the request in step 3?**
Server will receive when client send a request, in your case , step 2

Answer (score 0):

The data from the form is formatted into an HTTP request and sent over the network to the server directly. The server receives it from the network, puts it into memory (RAM), and calls your handler.

A TCP connection (that HTTP is built on) transmits sequences of bytes - that's why it is called a stream-oriented transport. This means you get the bytes in the same order you've sent them. An HTTP request is just a piece of text which looks similar to this:

```
POST /signup-controller HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 17

{"hello":"world"}
```

Note the blank line between the *headers* and the *body*. This gap is what allows Node.js (and HTTP servers in general) to quickly determine that the request is meant for `localhost:8080/signup-controller` using the POST method, without looking at the rest of the message! If the body was much larger (a real monster of a JSON), it would not make a difference, because the headers are still just a few short lines.

Thus, Node.js only has to buffer that part until the blank line (formally, `\r\n\r\n`) in memory. It gets to that point and it knows to call the HTTP request handler function that you've supplied. The rest - after the line break - is then available in the `req` object as a Readable Stream.

Even though there is some amount of buffering involved at each step (at the client, in switches, at intermediate routers, in the server's kernel, and finally in the server process), the communication is "direct" - one process on one host communicates with another process on another host, without involving the disk at any point.

Comment: You’re a legend! That was exactly the type of answer I was looking for. Thank you for the smooth explanation, and I really appreciated the tailoring and phrasing of certain things. You were speaking to me lol!! You def made my day. 

P.S. If you write articles, tutor, or do anything like that let me know. Id happily pay too!

Comment: @mobied There's plenty of information out there, and lots of good workshops. I don't do tutoring personally, though we run a small (~3000 members) non-profit community called WarsawJS that hosts monthly talks (live-streamed on YouTube) and on-line workshop sessions in tiny groups where you're able to ask, practice and learn. There's sometimes an English-language group if there's demand for it. Here's an example talk from one of our members that explains HTTP at a low level: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D1wykjTstr4